# ContentControl binding and DataTemplates produces binding error even if it works

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, contentcontrol

I'm trying to use a ContentControl and DataTemplate to switch viewmodels in my code. The code works, and it seems to bind properly, but I get an error in the output:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Value1' property not found on 'object' ''ViewModel2' (HashCode=1202201)'. BindingExpression:Path=Value1; DataItem='ViewModel2' (HashCode=1202201); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Value2' property not found on 'object' ''ViewModel1' (HashCode=7634749)'. BindingExpression:Path=Value2; DataItem='ViewModel1' (HashCode=7634749); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

The code of the MainView (the container):

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel1}" >
    <local:View1 DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UserControlContainer, Path=Content}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel2}" >
    <local:View2 DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UserControlContainer, Path=Content}"/>
</DataTemplate>
...
<ContentControl x:Name="UserControlContainer" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
```

The MainViewModel.cs contains:

```
    private ViewModelBase m_viewModel = null;
    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return m_viewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            m_viewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }
    private void EventTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentViewModel == null || CurrentViewModel.GetType() == typeof(ViewModel1))
        {
            CurrentViewModel = new ViewModel2();
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentViewModel = new ViewModel1();
        }
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
```

Both ViewModel1 and ViewModel2 have the same code, only that they refer to their own viewmodel and the property on it (Value1 for ViewModel1 and Value2 for ViewModel2):

ViewModel1:

```
public class ViewModel1 : ViewModelBase
{
    public double m_value = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.ToBinary()).NextDouble();

    public string Value1
    {
        get { return m_value.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

View1:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value1}"/>
```

I guess the problem is that when the timer changes the ViewModel in the property CurrentViewModel, the view that is not displayed is still in Memory and tries to bind to the wrong ViewModel (so View2 tries to get Value2 form ViewModel1).

Is there any way to solve this issue? So the binding only happens if the type of CurrentViewModel is of the right type. (I could use a converter and pass the expected type as a parameter but, is there any better solution?)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! You are right, it work without the DataContext. Thanks!

Comment: @EliArbel You probably want to put this in a separate answer instead of a comment, so OP can mark it as answered.